# Basic probability logic reasoning

Tags: probability

I would like to understand a basic concept of probability. Let's say we've got a box with 5 balls inside (4 white balls and 1 yellow balls).

The probability of taking a yellow ball from inside the box would be $\frac{1}{5}$, right?

It means 1 of 5 times we're going to take a yellow box, but why do we say 1 of 5 times? If I could try 10 times and take always a white ball, or even a bigger number of test cases $10^{29}$ tries and always (with really bad luck) take a white ball from the box

Why ? (Please explain for everyone's understanding)

Comment: It's one out of every five on average, not one if we do it five times.

Comment: People do speak about probability a bit informally.  What they ought to say is something like "on average, you'd expect to get the yellow $1$ time out of $5$."  As you say, it's perfectly possible (albeit improbable) that you'd draw $100$ whites in a row.

Comment: To stress: one of the constant challenges in probability and even more so in statistics is saying clearly and precisely what you mean by some computation or other.  Everybody speaks informally but that informality can lead to real confusion and misunderstanding.

Comment: The probability of that exists - it is not zero. If you do this experiment with replacement, there is a probability of $(4/5)^{10}  \approx 1/10$ chance that all balls will be white. It is just that the probability of that happening is low but of course one can get unlucky.